# Is it possible to install Scala support for RAD 8.5?

Tags: eclipse, rad

Is it possible to install Scala support into RAD 8.5? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search in Eclipse marketplace showed this is the most popular Scala p2

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/scala-ide

However, the latest version supports Eclipse 4.4, which is not supported by RAD 8.5 (8.5 includes Eclipse 3.6 http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1315604112137&duComponentIds=Desktop)

Looking at the Scala IDE site, there is support for Eclipse 3.8, but I cannot guarantee it will work.

http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

P2:  http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e38/scala211/stable/site

To install, go to Help > Install New software. Then in the Install new software wizard, enter the p2 address, select the Scala features to install, click Next, accept the license and then Finish.

I didn't try this on my own, so again I don't guarantee it will work.